# running a server from host on a docker-compose network

Tags: networking, docker-compose, ip-address

i have a network defined in my docker-compose.yaml:
`networks:
   docker_net:
       driver: bridge
       ipam:
           config:
             - subnet: 172.25.0.0/24`

I am trying to run some server from the host machine on a ip address that will be familiar to the docker-compose services (which are running on that docker-network).
What ip address should i use?
Can i connect from the host to the docker-network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host machine address can be reached on the first address in the docker network.
For example, for the above docker-network:
`networks:
   docker_net:
       driver: bridge
       ipam:
           config:
             - subnet: 172.25.0.0/24`

The host can be reached from the docker services as :
`172.25.0.1`